# How to exit from Coroutine scope when multi tasks is executing?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm working with a list of remote API call tasks and want to execute them in parallel using Kotlin Coroutines. Each task has a different execution period and returns a result upon completion.

My goal is to exit the current method as soon as the sum of an unknown number of tasks exceeds a specific value. It's acceptable to leave the remaining tasks running. However, I'm currently facing a challenge in achieving this exit condition within the Coroutine Scope Below is the code

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runInParallel()
}

fun runInParallel(): Int {
    val threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50)
    val scope = CoroutineScope(threadPool.asCoroutineDispatcher())
    var sum = 0

    runBlocking {
        (3..10).forEach{ n ->
            scope.launch {
                val deferredResult1 = async {
                    logTs( "register resultDelay3Deferred")
                    httpCallWithDelay(n)
                }

                val result1 = deferredResult1.await()

                println(result1)
                sum += result1
                println("current sum is $sum")
                if (sum > 10)
                   return sum     // here I cannot return or exit my current method
            }
        }
    }

    println("final sum is $sum")
}

fun httpCallWithDelay(delay: Int): Int {
    Thread.sleep(delay*1000)   // mock the period of API call latency
    return delay
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.cancel
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow


var sum = 0
val totalSum = MutableStateFlow(0)
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        totalSum.collect {
            println("final sum is $sum")

        }
    }
    runBlocking {
        runInParallel()
    }

}

suspend fun runInParallel() {
    coroutineScope {
        (3..10).map { n ->
            async {

                val result = async {
                    httpCallWithDelay(n)
                }.await()
                sum += result
                println("current sum is $sum")
                if (sum > 10) {
                    totalSum.emit(sum)
                    this.cancel()
                }
            }
        }.awaitAll()
    }
}

suspend fun httpCallWithDelay(delayTime: Int): Int {
    delay((delayTime * 1000).toLong())
    return delayTime
}
```

[image: output]